# How many ways to place three distinguishable tokens on the white spaces of a $4$-by-$4$ chess board?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle

[image: 4x4 Chessboard]

> Consider a $4\times 4$ chessboard like the one showing above. You want to place 3 distinguishable tokens. Each piece can only be placed in a white square, with only one piece per row and per column.
>
> How many ways are there to arrange the pieces?

I have one way of solving this, but I really want to know way to solve this "directly".

Solving Indirectly: All the cases ($8\cdot 7\cdot 6$) except the ones that break the rules.

So the cases that break the rules are:

Imagine that I fix two points horizontally that break the rule, then I have 6 places to place the other one ($6$), then I can do this in every row ($4$), I can do this vertically as well ($2$), and then I have to permute the 3 pieces ($3!$), however I will repeat the cases where I can't tell if I'm doing this vertically or horizontally(the intersections of both) so, those cases are, I fix two points and I have 2 places for other one ($2$), and I can do this in every row ($4$), and I don't multiply by two because I only want to eliminate one time, and I permute the 3 pieces ($3!$).

$$8\cdot 7\cdot 6 -[6\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 3!-2\cdot 4\cdot 3!]=96$$

Comment: What are _your_ thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Help us help you. Tell us what you know about the problem (what you may have tried, etc) and where exactly you got stuck. This information helps answerers target their responses to your skill level, while avoiding telling you things you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Answer (score 3):

You have $8$ possible places to put the pieces. After the first placement, two other places are ruled out due to being in the same row or column, so now you only have $5$ choices. Among these, $4$ choices will eliminate two more choices, and $1$ will eliminate none. Your answer is thus $8(4\times2+1\times4)=96$.

Comment: Alright, but shouldn't we multiply by 3! to permute the pieces? We are summing 2 different cases, but how do I know that I'm not overcounting(repeating cases?).

Comment: @NunoMateus:  you can place the pieces in any order you like.  You should not then multiply by $3!$ because the problem did not distinguish the order of placement.  There is nothing that makes the positions depend on the order of placement.

Comment: Yes the order doesn't matter, however the way this was solved like if there were 3 equal pieces, are you understanding what I'm saying?

Comment: @NunoMateus well, you can think of it like this. We start filling the spaces from the first piece $A$ first. And then, we consider what we can do with $B$, and then with $C$. So we do, in fact, account for the distinctness of the pieces.

Comment: Then where's the case that the first spot is filled by the piece B or C?
we're placing in this order (A,B,C)
What about the other five?
(A,C,B)
(B,A,C)
(B,C,A)
(C,A,B)
(C,B,A)

Comment: It doesn't matter which order we actually fill it in, all placements are accounted for.

Comment: Which step of the calculation guarantees me that?

Comment: Think about it yourself. Whichever order you fill in the pieces all possible placements are already counted in. Otherwise, can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: I can't come up with a counterexample because the result is correct but it doesn't make sense to me add both cases. Imagine the second case, 8*1*4, every "configuration" that follows the rule is already there, however I'm overcounting, because I'm distinguishing the first piece from the second, so I should divide by 2, and that gives me 16, now I want to permute the 3 pieces so 16*3!=96, this is the right result.
Doing this 8(4×2+1×4)=96 is a pure coincidence, or at least doesn't make sense to me

Comment: What happened to the $4\times2$ case?

Comment: Sorry for anwering so late. What do you mean by 4 x 2 case?

Comment: Well I broke the discussion into $4\times2$ and $1\times4$, but you only discussed the second case three comments ago. What happened to the first?

Answer (score 3):

The original version of the question specified that the pieces to place were a horse, a bishop, and a rook. According to a comment from OP, specifying the types was merely to make the pieces distinguishable. I edited the question to make remove the misleading terminology, and I'll leave this answer for posterity.

---

Why specify the types of pieces if we're not supposed to take their attack modes into account?

- Horses (aka, Knights) attack in an "L"-shaped manner (eg, two squares up, one square over), which moves them from a white square to a black square. Since no pieces are on black squares, this attack is moot.
- Rooks attack horizontally or vertically. Since no pieces are on the same row or column, this attack is also moot.
- Bishops attack diagonally. This attack remains viable, and *dramatically* reduces the possible placement of the other pieces.

There are 8 locations of the bishop, each of which limits to possible locations of the horse and rook. Here they are, grouped by symmetry:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As we see, only the first two bishop placements allow the horse and rook to be placed at all, and those placements are interchangeable. (We can't place pieces in the last four, since they'd be on the same row or column.)

> Thus, the total number of *attack-free* ways to place the pieces is: $4$.

Comment: I just translated the question, yes, their movements aren't taken in account, we just specified, only to mention that they're different, so the order does indeed matters.

Comment: You should've made that clear in the question. In any case, I'll leave my answer here, for those interested.

Comment: However, how can I solve the problem directly?

Answer (score 3):

Paint the white spaces blue (in the first and third columns) and red (in the second and fourth):

[image]

The rule against having tokens in the same row/column implies that each "color zone" has at most two tokens. On the other hand, with three tokens and only two zones, the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) requires that *at least* two tokens go into one zone. Thus, exactly two tokens go into one zone, leaving one token to go into the other zone.

Note that the two tokens in the same color zone must be placed in opposite corners of that zone. The token in the other color zone is unaffected by the placement of the first two tokens.

Now, first considering the tokens *indistinguishable*, we can count thusly:

- Which color zone has two tokens? $2$ choices.
- How to place those two tokens? $2$ ways.
- Where to place the third token? $4$ places.

and then

- How to make the tokens distinguishable? $3!$ ways.

> Therefore the total number of placements of distinguishable tokens is
>   $$2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3! = 96$$

Comment: +1 for the colouring. It makes the visualisation much easier :)